# pip install resulting in a TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

`pip install poetry` returns the following:

```
Collecting poetry
  Downloading poetry-1.1.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (175 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 175 kB 1.7 MB/s
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\polse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\polse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\polse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\polse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\polse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\polse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 372, in resolve
    name = min(unsatisfied_names, key=self._get_preference)
  File "C:\Users\polse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 177, in _get_preference
    return self._p.get_preference(
TypeError: PipProvider.get_preference() got an unexpected keyword argument 'backtrack_causes'
```

The same happens with any package. At first I thought it was my VPN, but after that the same error happens.

Comment: Try to check another version of Python and check it if it returns error again.

Comment: Upgrade your pip version. `python -m pip install -U pip`

Comment: @AKX using pip install at all returns that error

Comment: Then try https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/